# local condition on a topological manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I always read that an $n$-manifold is a topological space that locally looks like $\mathbb R^n$. But in the definition we require that each point has a neighborhood that is homeomorphic to "an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$" and not necessarily all of $\mathbb R^n$. Knowing that an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ need not be homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ this seems to be confusing!!

Comment: If $x\in V$, where $V$ is an open set in $\Bbb R^n$, then there is an open $B\in\Bbb R^n$ such that $x\in B\subseteq V$ and $B$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$, so the conditions are equivalent.

Comment: basically you are saying that every open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ contains a copy of $\mathbb R^n$. each $x\in M$ has a neighborhood $U_x$ homeomorphic to an open subset $V$ of $\mathbb R^n$. Now $V$ contains $B\cong \mathbb R^n$, but this does not say that $U_x\cong \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: No, I’m saying that every non-empty open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ contains a copy of $\Bbb R^n$ **around each of its points**. As I said: $x\in B\subseteq V$, **and** $B$ **is homeomorphic to** $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: I think $x$ is irrelevant here since the point $x$ is picked in $M$ not in $\mathbb R^n$, and for this $x\in M$ there is a neighb $U_x$ such that $U_x$ is $\cong$ to some subset $V\subset \mathbb R^n$.. am i missing something obvious?

Comment: @Pete: Will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that a point $x\in M$ has a nbhd $U$ homeomorphic to an open subset $V$ of $\Bbb R^n$. Let $h:U\to V$ be a homeomorphism. Since $h(x)\in V$, and $V$ is open in $\Bbb R^n$, there is an $r>0$ such that the open ball $B(h(x),r)\subseteq V$. Note that $B(h(x),r)$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$. Now let $B=h^{-1}[B(h(x),r)]$; then $B$ is homeomorphic to $B(h(x),r)$ and hence to $\Bbb R^n$, and clearly $x\in B\subseteq U$. Thus, $x$ has a nbhd homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$.

Thus, requiring that a point of $M$ have a nbhd homeomorphic to an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is in fact equivalent to requiring that the point have a nbhd homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$ itself. In particular, the two definitions of *manifold* are equivalent.